# Trying to convert png rgb to cmyk but how do i found out the question attempting to convert

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, color, png, file-conversion

Where to find this information out below?
Is the conversion using the right color profile?
The black produced is the one you need?
Do the gradients look right, and have a smooth color transition?
Do you need "pure" colors?
Do you need another kind of color conversion, like perceptual or colorimetric?

Comment: We can not know if your using the right profile, you need to know this info. The balck produced is what the profile does, again we can not know if its right you need to know this (note this si really the only reason to convert to cmyk in your case). do the gradiesnts look right, again you need to know this or provide file. "pure colors" no idea. As for color conversion intent, yeah most likely you need the  saturation intent,

Answer (score 1):

That's alot of questions with a single answer:

- PNG does *not* support CMYK
- PNG *only* works in RGB

Comment: Yes, although PNGs also support Indexed colour, but that's no use for print either.